# VS 2015 and Cordova 6.3 debugging on IOS physical device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I'm building an IOS app using Visual Studio 2015 and Cordova 6.3. Remotebuild is running on a MacInCloud shared server and the devicesupport folder is copied locally to C:\temp\DeviceSupport because I don't have permissions to map a share to the Mac. The version of XCode is 7.3.1 (7D1014) and the device support folder contains a subfolder for IOS 9.3 which is what my device is running.

Using this configuration I'm able to build my app successfully and it deploys to my registered and connected physical IOS device. However, I'm not able to debug and get this message in Visual Studio:

2>Starting idevicedebugserverproxy.exe at port 3000.
2>Timed out connecting to local iOS device.
2>Failed to launch the app on the device. Check that the device is connected, awake, and unlocked.

The device is connected, awake and unlocked.

Any suggestions please?

BWG

Comment: I had the same issue and open the app directly on the device at the time VS is waiting.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Bjoerg: In my case that causes VS to hang and I need to restart it.